# Alternate for getInfowindow in V3

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3

```
 Is there any alternate code for getting infowindow from maps v3. Previously i had v2 version code as 
`MapWidget map = new MapWidget();
InfoWindow info = map.getInfoWindow()
info.open(marker.getLatLng(),new InfoWindowContent("Test"));`
```

I cant find getInfoWindow in gwt-maps-3.8.0. Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ??

```
InfoWindow.open(MapWidget mapWidget)
```

Which Opens this InfoWindow on the given map.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got.. In Maps V2, there is no initialization for InfoWindow. Instead we are getting from map as `InfoWindow info = map.getInfoWindow();`
In Map V3 we have the syntax as 
             `InfoWindowOptions options = InfoWindowOptions.create();
          options.setContent("Test);
          options.setPosition(LatLng.create(24.796708, 46.691895));
          InfoWindow info = InfoWindow.create(options);
          info.open(map);`

For Details click [Here](http://ameenit.blogspot.in/2013/03/displaying-infowindow-in-maps-v3.html).